# Python's socket library blocks even when network interface is down

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-requests, blocking

I'm trying to test how my python program reacts to a network issue. So when it tries to make a request to the network, i shutdown the network interface(e.g wifi, modem). But the program blocks after doing this.

I thought it was a problem in my program but after some debugging, i discovered it's from the underlying socket library. I don't know how long the blocking time is but, is there anything I can do to fine-tune the library to return quickly.

I'm using the requests library.

my program makes a couple of:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session();
res = session.get("https://domain/path");
```

Then in the middle of it all, I just shut the interface down.

Comment: so now you know how your program reacts to a network issue. Mission accomplished?

Comment: not really, my program is blocked from handling it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `timeout` parameter to specify the number of "seconds" Requests will wait for your client to establish a connection to a remote machine.

```py
requests.get('https://example.com', timeout=5)
```

Default value of timeout is set to `None` which means it will wait forever for a response.

You can also use `requests` documentation here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Also, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example for your questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: But, don't you think this solution prevents the program from pushing through a slow network??.

Comment: @SheriffMobolajiEsseson No. it will not prevent the program from pushing through a slow network. However, if the network is so slow that it doesn't respond after the specified timeout, it will close the connection.

Comment: Also, if you want the request to be non-blocking, i.e. you want your program to continue executing other lines of code while sending or receiving TCP packets simultaneously, I would suggest using `grequests` library which can send asynchronous requests. (https://pypi.org/project/grequests/) Or if you want to handle the process yourself using `requests` library, you could use `threading` library to make your program multi-thread.

Comment: ok, thank you. I think i prefer the timeout way.

Comment: You're Welcome. If an answer was useful to you, please consider upvoting it and if it solved your problem, accept it as the best answer.

Comment: I already tried it, I'm not eligible to cast votes yet.

Answer (score 0):

> ... i shutdown the network interface(e.g wifi, modem). But the program blocks after doing this.

This is expected. A network interface down is from the perspective of TCP just one of several possibilities for causing **temporary** problems delivering data. TCP is designed to deal with it. If there are outstanding data they will be redelivered after the connectivity is there again - at least if it does not take too long to recover. If there are no outstanding data it does not matter - TCP connections can be idle for hours or even days and it does not matter if connectivity temporary goes down in between.

If you want to detect connection loss (which can also be cause by problems on the path, even if the network interface is up) you can use timeouts so that it does not wait forever. Also TCP keep-alive can be used, in which case it will regularly check if delivery is possible by exchanging packets with zero payload.

Comment: Makes sense. But, is there a limit to keep-alive packets (without a response from the other end of the connection) that can be sent before tcp calls it quit; destroying the socket unilaterally??

Comment: @SheriffMobolajiEsseson: yes, this is how TCP keep-alive works. Depending on the OS socket specific settings can be used for how often keep-alive packets are sent and how many replies can be missing before the sockets is considered broken. See for example https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#programming